# Mark item with "like" button SharePoint 2007

Tags: list, list-form

sharePoint 2007.

I create custom list for my team.
Team member can create a new item and all other team members can see this item.

is it possible to produce the following:
team member will be able to do "like" or "I did not like"
on each item list.

notice:
I can not use the sharePoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to create a survey for each item.You can create question to like or dislike in the survey. However, You will need to manage\create the survey manually.

The other way is to create a custom webpart\ control or field type.But this will need server side permissions to deploy.

Comment: I created new survey list. with one question (likr or dislike). now I want to attached this survey to each item in the custom list. is it possible?